# How to show independence of followingIto integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Hi: I have a question about how to show the independence of two random variables of form It$\hat{o}$ integral.

> suppose the sequence {$w_{k}$}=$\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\cdots$. Given a standard Brownian motion $W_{[0,T]}$.Define random variables $Y_{k} = \int_{0}^{T}sin(w_{k}t)dW_{t}$.

And I want to show that these $Y_{k}$'s are independent variables (I hope they are).

I start with standard way, so to show two random variable $X,Y$ are independent , it's equivalent to show $\mathbf{P}[X|Y]=\mathbf{P}[X],\mathbf{P}[Y|X]=\mathbf{P}[Y]$ namely knowing the other one won't help in predicting this one. But then I am stuck here because I don't know how to continue to calculate the $\mathbf{P}$ there since there are It$\hat{o}$ integral involved...

So could someone help to take a look, if $Y_{k}$'s are independent , how can I possibly show that? (My way starting out is not so good and convenient I think)

Thanks in advance for your help~

Comment: Possible suggestion: Build a sequence of adapted random variables, then show independence of the families.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Hi, thanks for the reply. Are you implying the sigma-algebra? Could you please explain a little bit in detail? because I actually don't know too much about the rigorous filtration or family. Thanks

Comment: @SeanRoberson Hi I did a bit of search in order to get your point. So the adapted random variables refer to "non-anticipating" variables, so here the sin(wk t) is only a function of time t , so definitely adapted. So then do you mean I need to show the independence of the family of {sin(wk t)}? Thanks